# Strongly connected graph proof

Tags: graphs, graph-traversal

Here I have a proof related to strongly connected graph from Algorithms book.

[image]

However, when I run DFS on the following 2 strongrly connected graph, I get different result than the proof.

[image]

According to property, highest post number in C is bigger than the highest post number in D but it is not. Where am I making mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your post-traversal numbering of the component $C$ is incorrect. The vertex labeled as $1,6$ was assigned its post-traversal number too early; a depth-first search will also explore the vertices of $D$ before assigning the post-traversal number to this vertex.

Comment: Thank you! I figured out too.